# How to auto scroll Appium Server Console log at bottom

Tags: android, appium, mobile-automation, logs

**Problem :** I used to view/analyze Appium server Console logs during any test cases execution. But the problem is Appium server console always Auto scroll to top which result hiding latest logs. I have to manually scroll to down to see the latest log.

How should I manage to make Console log show latest logs and always scroll to down like eclipse console. I am looking for permanent solution.

Appium Windows 1.4.16.1

Refer screen shot (hide some workspace and apk details using pen)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you start your appium through terminal, your appium server logs will show the latest logs, provided you don't manually intervene while the logs are getting generated.

you can start appium server using the command below

appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4444

Here a is your local host and 4444 is the port